# Find & Extract hashtags in text

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I'm looking for an easy/quick way to identify and extract hashtags from a string, and temporarily store them separately - e.g.:

If I have the following string:

> 2017-08-31 This is a useless sentence being used as an example. #Example #Date:2017-09-01 #NothingWow (and then some more text for good measure).

Then I want to be able to get this:

```
#Example
#Date:2017-09-01
#NothingWow
```

I figured storing it in a *TStringList* should be sufficient until I'm done. I just need to store them outside of the original string for easier cross referencing, then if the original string changes, add them back at the end.
(*but that's easy - its the extracting part I'm having trouble with*)

It should start at the # and end/break when it encounters a *[space]*.

The way I initially planned it was to use Boolean flags (*defaulted to False*), then check for the different hashtags, set them to true if found, and extract anything after a *[:]* separately.
(*but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it*)

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parse the string character by character. When you encounter a `#` make a note of the position. When you encounter white space or the end of the string, add the hash tag to your list. Then, if there is more string left, continue through it as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shows a simple console application which you could use as the basis
for a solution.  It works because assigning your input string to the `DelimitedText` property of a `StringList` causes the `StringList` to parse the input into a series of space-limited lines.  It is then a simple matter to look for the ones which start with a `#`.

The code is written as a Delphi console application but should be trivial to convert to Lazarus/FPC.

Code:

```
program HashTags;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

procedure TestHashTags;
var
  TL : TStringList;
  S : String;
  i : Integer;
begin
  TL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    S := '2017-08-31 This is a useless sentence being used as an example. #Example #Date:2017-09-01 #NothingWow (and then some more text for good measure)';
    TL.DelimitedText := S;
    for i := 0 to TL.Count - 1 do begin
    if Pos('#', TL[i]) = 1 then
      writeln(i, ' ', TL[i]);
    end;
  finally
    TL.Free;
  end;
  readln;
end;

begin
  TestHashTags;
end.
```

Comment: `TL := TStringList.Create; try..`

Comment: @Sami:  Thanks for spotting.  It was a bit of faulty editing.

Comment: I see what you did...I just need two _StringLists_ - first one to delimit the text with, and the second to hold the actual results - thanks.